# D8 Views Template Suggestions Being Ignored

Tags: views, 8, theming

I went through other questions/answers on this topic and I am still stumped. My added template suggestion for a Views Exposed form is being ignored.

```
function talon_theme_suggestions_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
      $suggestions[] = $variables[form]['#id']. "__ef";
}
```

Template name in theme: `views-exposed-form-views-programs-block-1--ef.html.twig`

Theme Debug lists suggestion as: `views-exposed-form-views-programs-block-1--ef.html.twig`

Answer (score 5):

A template name suggestion has to start with the theme hook and two underscores. You find the theme hook in the twig debug output, in this case `views-exposed-form`:

```
$suggestions[] = 'views_exposed_form__' . $mycustomdata;
```